# Entered wrong value. goto Start;

Tags: c#

*Edit.
Based on the answers received I realized that I am asking more than I know about at this early stage in my learning and as such, I have decided to forget this question until I have learnt and understand more. I do not want to overstep and confuse myself.*

Just a newbie looking for some guidance.

From a previous question I asked here, I was introduced to the goto Start; in the switch statement.

I started using it and it had me thinking that I wanted the program to go to the start in the event the user entered an invalid input. Example, in my calculator below, if the user enters something other than a number, how do I get the program to disregard the input and prompt the user again to enter a number? Maybe even display an "invalid input. please try again" to the user.

Right now, if anything but a number is entered, the console crashes and throws me an error.

Thanks in advance for the assistance

```
      int num1, num2, output;
        string  op;

        Console.Write("\n\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Calculator\n");
        Console.WriteLine("=============");
        Console.Write("\n\n");

        Start:

        Console.Write("Please enter first number:");
        num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        Console.Write("Please enter second number: ");
        num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Operator:

        Console.WriteLine("Please select operator: ");
        Console.WriteLine("\nAddition : +");
        Console.WriteLine("Multiplication: *");
        Console.WriteLine("Division: /");
        Console.WriteLine("Subtraction: -");
        Console.Write("Enter Operator: ");
        op = Console.ReadLine();




        switch (op)
        {
            case "+":
                output = num1 + num2;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} added to {1} = {2}", num1, num2, output);
                break;

            case "*":
                output = num1 * num2;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} multiplied by {1} = {2}", num1, num2, output);
                break;

            case "/":
                if (num2 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cannot divide by zero. Please try again");
                    goto Start;

                }
                else
                {
                    output = num1 / num2;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} divided by {1} = {2}", num1, num2, output);
                    break;
                }

            case "-":
                output = num1 - num2;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} minus{1} = {2}", num1, num2, output);
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid operator. Please try again\n");
                goto Operator;                     

         }

       Console.WriteLine("\nPress enter to continue....");
       Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, whatever you do, do **NOT** use `goto`. Ever. Maybe except in `switch` to fall down to other `case`, but even that should be very rare. It makes your code unreadable, confusing and hard to maintain. Please see [spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code).

That said, you should do `Int32.TryParse` instead of `Convert` if you are not sure if the input is valid:

```
int num1;
do
{
    Console.Write("Please enter first number:");
} while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num1));
```

And change your `switch` to something like this (to avoid `goto`):

```
bool inputOk = false;
while (!inputOk)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please select operator: ");
    //...
    op = Console.ReadLine();

    inputOk = true;
    switch (op)
    {
        //...
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid operator. Please try again\n");
            inputOk = false;
            break;
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with do/while statements as yet :(

Comment: @Jude I don't know which constructs you are familiar with, but it can be rewritten with any loop. If you are having problems, let me know which one you choose and I will refactor it for the kind of loop you choose.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not familiar with much as I just started about two/three weeks ago.

I think I should just forget my question for now until I start learning more and am able to understand more. 

I may have over stepped.

Thank you for your assistance though.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but this may be what you want:

```
Start:

Console.Write("Please enter first number:");
if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num1))
    goto Start;
//num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


Console.Write("Please enter second number: ");
num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Operator:

...
```

And perhaps the same for num2, if you need.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is through the use of EXCEPTION.  Since you are learning,  I would not provide a sample code on how to do it but would want you to read about it [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_exception_handling.htm) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173162.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`goto` inside a switch tries to go to the defined case. In your example there is no start case so it doesn't know where to go.

more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx).

I would suggest using methods though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think goto statements are suitable in this situation. Your code can get really messy if you have a lot of them. Using `FormatException` isn't recommended either, since throwing an exception takes a long time.

I think you should use `Int32.TryParse` instead.

Here's a piece of sample code. See if you can apply this to your program.

```
int input;
while(true) {
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
    bool succeeds = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input);
    if (!succeeds) {
        Console.WriteLine("Input Invalid! Try again!");
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
// make use of input here
```

Comment: That's a little bit too confusing for me, believe it or not.

Comment: I think i'll just forget about it for now until I learn some more :)

Answer (score 1):

```
     int num1, num2, output;
    string  op;

    Console.Write("\n\n");
    Console.WriteLine("Calculator\n");
    Console.WriteLine("=============");
    Console.Write("\n\n");

Start:

    do
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter valid first number:");
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num1));


    do
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter valid second number:");
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num2));

    Operator:

    Console.WriteLine("Please select operator: ");
    Console.WriteLine("\nAddition : +");
    Console.WriteLine("Multiplication: *");
    Console.WriteLine("Division: /");
    Console.WriteLine("Subtraction: -");
    Console.Write("Enter Operator: ");
    op = Console.ReadLine();




    switch (op)
    {
        case "+":
            output = num1 + num2;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} added to {1} = {2}", num1, num2, output);
            break;

        case "*":
            output = num1 * num2;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} multiplied by {1} = {2}", num1, num2, output);
            break;

        case "/":
            if (num2 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot divide by zero. Please try again");
                goto Start;

            }
            else
            {
                output = num1 / num2;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} divided by {1} = {2}", num1, num2, output);
                break;
            }

        case "-":
            output = num1 - num2;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} minus{1} = {2}", num1, num2, output);
            break;

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid operator. Please try again\n");
            goto Operator;                     

     }

   Console.WriteLine("\nPress enter to continue....");
   Console.ReadLine();
```